# Problem with template.dotx metadata

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, word, template

I stumbled on a weird problem yesterday and I found why this occurs, but I am clueless on how to resolve that.

First, in our SharePoint site, we have a list named «**Categories**» where we have different categories defined and where we can set a **default value**.

We have also a Site column (Choice) «**Category**» where we have the list of **Categories** and the default value who is set with the one select in the **Categories** list. This column is needed for when we edit document category through SP sites.

That is for the introduction!

**The problem:**

When I change the default value in the Categories list, each existing Document libraries have their site column «Category» updated with the new default value. But when I create a new document in those lists, the default value (Word metadata) in the category property is set with the old default value. And I found why. It's because the template.docx associate with the list, contain the category property set with the initial default value.

**Is there a way to refresh this template.docx for all existing Document Library when the default value is updated?**